# In game client feature for recording Moonlight Blade game play and replay it like DOTA 2 or LoL?

Tags: recording, moonlight-blade

I do not want to use video recording tools like ShadowPlay or FRAPS.
I am looking for in game client feature like DOTA 2 has.

Moonlight Blade official website: http://wuxia.qq.com/main.shtml

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is it just doesn't exist yet.

By definition, in-game features are completely dependent on the developers making it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes they are dependent on developers those are making yet. I was searching for any command line command or something which I didn't come across so asked this question.

Comment: @AnuragDaware If that is what you are looking for, please edit your question so it contains the tag of the game you are trying to record, so we can answer your problem.

Comment: @angussidney can you please create the tag of 'Moonlight Blade'. It doesn't exist and I cannot create it. What is solution for this?

Comment: @AnuragDaware Edited. I personally do not know the answer for that game, but others might. Just wait for an answer!

Comment: It would work better if you add a link to the game's site.  I'm getting hits for an mmo when i search that name.

Comment: @Nelsin added official game's site.